# PHP and antiword are not correctly parsing cyrillic text

Tags: php, character-encoding, internationalization, ms-office

I am trying to parse an MS Office 2003 document using antiword on my Linux server. But it will not parse cyrillic text correctly.

It returns something like this:

```
??? ???? ???????????
```

Does anybody know of a way to correctly parse a MS Office 2003 document that contains cyrillic text?

Comment: This is an encoding issue, what code have you used to parse the text?

Comment: I trying execute it in command line `antiword test.doc` in my php code I using the same way `shell_exec('antiword test.doc')`

Comment: @vladimir does it work correctly when you do it from the command line?

Comment: no it returns not correct result. It returns `??? ???? ???????????`

Comment: Are you certain that the DOC file isn't corrupted? Using antiword from the command line in a Mac OS X computer, I have no problems getingt the Cyrillic letters of such a document to render. Does it work from the command line for you?

Comment: Yes DOC file isn`t corrupted. It doesn`t work from the command line correct. It returns `??? ???? ???????????`

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue with cyrillic text

good documentation you may see [here](http://pubsvn.ez.no/community/trunk/extension/indexing/bin/antiword/win32/DOCS/FAQ)

working code follows:

```
$content = shell_exec('/usr/bin/antiword -m cp1251.txt '.$filename);
var_dump($content);
```

Pay attention to param -m ( character mapping file)

you forgot to set correct mapping file

---

Piece of doc concerns mapping file:

```
Q9: Which mapping file (-m option) is correct in my situation?
A9: The correct mapping file depends on the character set you need for output
    in a specific language.
    For Western European languages (like English, French, German) this is
    8859-1.txt. (OS/2: cp1252.txt) (DOS: cp850.txt)
    For Eastern European languages (like Polish, Czech, Slovak, Croatian) this
    is 8859-2.txt. (OS/2: cp1250.txt) (DOS: cp852.txt)
    For Esperanto use 8859-3.txt.
    For Russian use 8859-5.txt or koi8-r.txt. (OS/2: cp1251.txt)
     (DOS: cp866.txt)
    For Ukrainian use koi8-u.txt.
    For Arabic use 8859-6.txt. (DOS: cp864.txt)
    For Hebrew use 8859-8.txt. (DOS: cp862.txt)
    For Thai use 8859-11.txt.
    If your system supports it, you might also try UTF-8.txt.

    NOTE: UTF-8 also enables Antiword to show text in languages like Chinese,
          Japanese and Korean.
```

Answer (score 0):

Antiword has an encoding parameter, maybe you give that a try:

```
 shell_exec('antiword -X UTF-8 test.doc')
```

Or use `koi8-r`, and then convert in php via [`iconv()`](http://php.net/iconv)

---

Alternatively try LibreOffice in cmdline mode

```
 shell_exec('soffice --headless --convert-to txt test.doc')
```

Comment: I have a super old version `0.32` from 2001, and it has.

Comment: The [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/antiword) implies that antiword is already using utf8.